# Есть ли плагины для IDE PascalABC.NET?

Tags: ide, плагин, pascalabc.net

Если есть то где их найти? Нигде сам не нашёл, но на стр вики проекта пишут что их можно добавлять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможность есть, по сути это это обычная библиотека (скомпилированный исходник) с подключением библиотеки VisualPascalABCPlugins, это даёт интерфейс взаимодействия со средой из кода.

Плагинов нет.

Видимо отсутствует необходимость расширять IDE, у паскаля на сегодня основная функция это -- обучение. Или более серьёзный вариант Delphi, тогда вам к Embarcadero и это другая история (там плагинов/компоненты десятки тонн). Или вы хотите на паскале StackOverflow переписать? но вы по прежнему можете подключить любую из библиотек к самому паскалю.